# How to convert ISO week number to US week number in C++

Tags: c++, boost, gregorian-calendar

I am using boost gregorian library for date calculation in c++
boost gregorian returns week number in ISO format but I want week number in US format.

how I can get week number in US format.

please see link https://planetcalc.com/1252/

e.g.

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::gregorian::date myday1 = boost::gregorian::from_simple_string("2005-1-1");
    int weekNum1 = myday1.week_number(); //return ISO which is 53 //week 1 as US method
    boost::gregorian::date myday2 = boost::gregorian::from_simple_string("2005-1-2");
    int weekNum2 = myday2.week_number(); //return ISO which is 53 //week 2 as US method
    return 0;
}
```

Using visual studio 2019 community on windows 10

Comment: I'd think something along the lines of adding the day of week for the first of january to the day of week for the target year and then dividing would work.

Comment: What do you mean "Format". It's an integer. There is no format. Can you give examples? I don't see how the link helps and also, that's not how asking questions on SO works.

Comment: I want week 1 for 2005-1-1 & week 2 for 2005-1-2 but it returns 53. I check c# .net where we can set culture info and there it works but in cpp I am unable to find equivalent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find no direct way in C++ or any library which support US method for week number,
So I have to use CLR dll and call it from native C++.

```
//Header file
#pragma once
__declspec(dllexport) int GetWeekNumber(int year, int month, int day);
```

C++/CLI File

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CLRDll.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Globalization;

namespace CLRDll
{
   public ref  class CCalender
   {
        static CultureInfo^ cinfo = gcnew CultureInfo("en-US");
        static Calendar^ cal = cinfo->Calendar;
        // Gets the DTFI properties required by GetWeekOfYear.
        static CalendarWeekRule^ myCWR = cinfo->DateTimeFormat->CalendarWeekRule;
        static DayOfWeek^ myFirstDOW = cinfo->DateTimeFormat->FirstDayOfWeek;

      public:
        int GetWeekNumber(int year, int month, int day);
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
 }

 int CLRDll::CCalender::GetWeekNumber(int year, int month, int day)
 {
     DateTime^ dt = gcnew DateTime(year, month, day);
     return cal->GetWeekOfYear(*dt, *myCWR, *myFirstDOW);
 }

 __declspec(dllexport) int GetWeekNumber(int year, int month, int day)
 {
     CLRDll::CCalender c;
    return c.GetWeekNumber(year, month, day);
 }
```